# Why is CaO a lewis base

Tags: acid-base

We know that $\ce{CaO}$ is a base. But when I wanted to know which theory proves this fact, I got to know that Lewis theory explains this through a reaction with $\ce{SO_3}$. But the definition of Lewis base are those substances which can donate lone pair electrons. We all know $\ce{CaO}$ is an ionic compound. So how can it possibly have lone pair electrons? Moreover, there is no central atom in $\ce{CaO}$. So whose lone pair electrons will we be counting if there were one?

Comment: [Why does calcium oxide react with sulfur dioxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46678)

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think your conceptual problem is with the man-made classification of acid-base reactions and other associated labels. Chemical elements and compounds do not care what labels humans are applying onto them...they will combine the way Nature and its laws of physics have allowed them. In the link suggested by andselisk, the answer hinting at the Lux–Flood theory is a better answer.

Comment: O^2- ion has 4 pairs ready to react, making it a base much stronger than OH-, which is its conjugate acid.